# How to Write "decimal-to-hex-converted" numbers into a .csv file with PHP

Tags: php, loops, hex, decimal

Trying to write a set of numbers that are converted from decimal to hexadecimal to a .csv file.
The following code will put the desired output in the BROWSER;

```
for ($i=0;$i<=15;$i++ ) {
    for ($j=0;$j<=15;$j++ ) {           
    echo dechex($i).",".dechex($j)." - ";}}
```

[A portion of browser output is attached. from '0,0' to 'f,f'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKsFv.png)

The following code, intended to write (the same output as browser) into a .csv file, goes to an infinite loop. Help is appreciated.

```
$file = "colors.csv";       
$FH = fopen ($file, 'w') or die ("$file cannot  be opened for writing.");

for ($i=0;$i<=15;$i++ ) {   
for ($j=0;$j<=15;$j++ ) {           
        $i=dechex($i);
        $j=dechex($j);      
              fwrite ($FH, "$i");
              fwrite ($FH, ",");
              fwrite ($FH, "$j");
              fwrite ($FH, "\n");}}
```

@Mark Baker, @Nico Hasse,(10 hours later) Thanks for your inputs, the following code
is working. The main deferences are:

1-`fopen()` is placed inside both `for()` loops. 
2- In`fwrite($FH,"w")`, "w" is changed to "a" 
3- As for `$i,$j>9`, hexadecimal#s cannot be incremented by regular means,
at the end of the loop `$i,$j` are converted back to decimal.

```
`for ($i=0;$i<=15;$i++ ) {
    for ($j=0;$j<=15;$j++ ) {
$file = "colors.csv";
        $FH = fopen ($file, "a") or die ("$file cannot be opened for writing.");        
            $i=dechex($i);
            $j=dechex($j);
            fwrite($FH, $i.",".$j."\n");
            $i=hexdec($i);
            $j=hexdec($j);
            fclose($FH);}
                }`
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? And please use better formatting for your code

Comment: Use temporary variables instead of `$i=dechex($i)` and `$j=dechex($j);` (e.g. `$tmpI=dechex($i)` and `$tmpJ=dechex($j);`) otherwise you're modifying the values you use for your loop counting inside the loop that they're supposed to be counting

Comment: Or use `fwrite ($FH, dechex($i));` and `fwrite ($FH, dechex($j));`

Comment: And note that a csv file row should end with `\n`, not with an html `<br>`

Comment: @MarkBaker: Thanks for suggestions. With    `$tmpI=dechex($i)` , again i got the infinite loop, with     `fwrite($FH, dechex($i)),` I get the fatal error  Function name must be a string in C:...test4.php on line.

Comment: @Mark Baker, @Nico Hasse, Thanks for input, the following code works. Main deferences:1-`fopen()` is placed inside
 loops. 2- In`fwrite($FH,"w")`, "w" changed to "a" 3- As 
for ` $i,$j>9 ` hex#s cannot be incremented by regular means,
at the end of the loop `$i,$j ` are converted back to decimal.`for ($i=0;$i<=15;$i++ ) {
 for ($j=0;$j<=15;$j++ ) {
$file = "colors.csv";
  $FH = fopen ($file, "a") or die ("$file cannot be opened for writing.");  
   $i=dechex($i);
   $j=dechex($j);
   fwrite($FH, $i.",".$j."\n");
   $i=hexdec($i);
   $j=hexdec($j);
   fclose($FH);}
    }`

Comment: `fopen() is placed inside both for() loops.` Why?!?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with something as simple as

```
$file = "colors.csv";       
$FH = fopen ($file, 'w')
    or die ("$file cannot  be opened for writing.");

for ($i=0; $i<=15; $i++) {   
    for ($j=0; $j<=15; $j++) {           
        fwrite ($FH, dechex($i));
        fwrite ($FH, ",");
        fwrite ($FH, dechex($j));
        fwrite ($FH, "\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work because: 1-Through every iteration the file has to be opened, a new line of data written into, and be closed. Putting the 1st 2 lines outside the 2 loops doesn't do that. 2-In `fopen($FH, "w"), w`  will deletes and writes new data, but`  "a" ` appends to the existing list and creates a complete list of sets from  `(0,0) to (f,f) ` ...continued...

Comment: (....continued.....)3- As soon as  loop iteration reaches 9, as the next hexadecimal #s are the letters "a,b,c,...",  and as 9+1 is not equal to a, the iteration goes into an infinite loop, therefore after fwrite() both $i and $j  which are now in hexadecimal format, have to be returned back to decimal format, so that incrementing them becomes possible. Just try the new code and see that it works.

Comment: WHY does the file have to be opened in each iteration? What logical reason is there to do that (besides creating a lot of overhead)? Once a file is open, it remains open until it's closed again, either by an explicit call to close(), or when the script terminates.

Comment: What do you mean about 9+1 is not equal to a? 9+1 is `10`, which gives a result of `a` when you call `dechex()`.... calling `dechex()` doesn't change `$i` from `10` to `a` (so there is no need to convert anything back), but it returns an `a` as the result of that function call. You seem to have a lot of misunderstandings about how PHP functions work

Comment: Just run the code and see if it works or not - [demo](https://3v4l.org/2hFaP) - and then convince me that is an infinite loop

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I am still scratching my head as to where did i make such a mistake, I guess this proves that i still have a lot to learn.